# NSInvalidArgumentException on save an array of custom objects in UserDefaults

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I would like to save an array of object in my UserDefaults

```
let thisAction = action(ts: String(Date().timeStamp()), winner: winner)
actions.append(thisAction)
UserDefaults.standard.set(actions, forKey: "currentMatch")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

But I have the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object

Comment: Try Objective-C objects (NSArray, NSDictionary).  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH3-97383 .  It is stated that objects of types NSData, NSDate, NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, and NSURL can be saved, got.

Comment: Please [search on the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+Attempt+to+insert+non-property+list+object) before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Objective-C objects (NSArray, NSDictionary).
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH3-97383 .

It is stated that objects of types NSData, NSDate, NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, and NSURL can be saved, got.

So, a possible solution is:

```
struct Action { var timestamp: TimeInterval; var winner: String }

var actions: [Action] = []

...
actions.map({ ["time": $0.timestamp, "winner": $0.winner ] as NSDictionary })
// You could also convert the actions manually one by one into NSDictionary
// and append them to an [NSDictionary]



UserDefaults.standard.set(actions as NSArray, forKey: "currentMatch")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Swift arrays and dictionary can be *bridged* to `NSArray`, `NSDictionary` respectively.

You can also use Codable, it can serialize property lists also.

Comment: Ok thx, I serialized my object in json to add it as an array of string in my UserDefaults.

Comment: You do not need any of the casts in this code. And you do not need the call to `synchronize`.